# Block changes do not save in admin/structure/block/ page

Tags: 7, blocks

I have a large number of blocks in a Drupal website. Now I can not save changes in region and order of blocks in admin/structure/block/ page.

There is no message at the top of the page, no Javascript error in console and no error in the error log of my cpanel.

I have increased max_input_vars in php.ini file to 5000 or upper and checked the changes in admin/reports/status/php/ to be sure about it but still block changes does not save.

How can I get out of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, this happens when you disable the `Main page content` block and save the changes. After doing this, clicking save will not do anything.

The simple fix is to enable the `Main page content` block, you should put it back under the Content region.

[image]

Comment: The main page content block is enable and in content region.

Comment: @shekoufeh try checking the Drupal error log `admin/reports/dblog`

Comment: there is nothing about it in error log of drupal!

Comment: Do you know **why** such disable may cause this? Maybe you're aware of some issue about it on D.O?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I learned this from experience/experimenting, so I do not know why, feel free to shed some light on this if you know something.

Comment: Aha, that's what you mean ... As per your "***This is known to happen***", I thought you knew about some issue about it somewhere. Maybe you should change that intro to something like "*I learned from experience/experimenting*"?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Drupal 7. How to understand the issue? This happens when in a given region, you have used all allowed weight numbers from -55 to 55. Number 0 can be used for multiple blocks but the system will not behave the right way. Some people suggest you remove few blocks. That works, but what if you do not want to delete blocks?

In my case, I went to admin/structure/block then Show row weights. I manually started the numbering from -500 to 500 leaving free large slots between rows. After saving the page, you will notice the changes. Let me know if this solves your issue. Cheers.